# Android how to add activities to backstack like fragments

Tags: android, addition, back-stack

I have multiple activities. I want to add them to backstack, when i open the activities one by one like fragments. Will it be possible for activities to add them in backstack like fragments. Any help will be useful. Thanks!

Comment: By default activities are added to backStack

Comment: But if i open an activity, it will added two times in backstack. So that's themain issue. How to resolve that.

Comment: dont start activity from intent again then it will not be added two times in backStack

Comment: I have two buttons say button1 and button2 at bottom of screen. Suppose, when i click on button1, activity A start. When click on button2, activity B start. Then, if i click on button1 again, activity A start again. So it will be added two times in backstack. SO how to handle this issue.

Comment: if you start activity A then how you are coming back to main screen?

Comment: please post your code for better explanation

Answer (score 0):

Just launch new activities on top of an activity and do not finish the current activity. Android will maintain an activity stack of its own. you will return to the previous activity once you finish the current activity

Comment: But if i open an activity, it will added two times in backstack. So that's themain issue. How to resolve that. –

Comment: just finish the activity at the top, the activity below it be resumed. I suggest you go through developer.android.com to understand the activity life cycle

Answer (score 0):

use this code when you are switching from one activity to another

```
 Intent a = new Intent(this, A.class);
    a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(a);
```

this will give u

```
A>b>c>d
a>b>c
a>b
a
```